# For asp.net app different session id for single iis hosted 2 applications

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, session-state

I need to get different session IDs for single iis hosted application
 As in session fixation on login session id get regenerated. Then 2 - app which are hosted on same iis can not run simultaneously.

In Login button as i tried to regenerate the session id:

```
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
    string oldId = manager.GetSessionID(Context);
    string newId = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
    bool redirected = false;
    bool isAdded = false;
    manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newId, out redirected, out isAdded);
    HttpApplication ctx = (HttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
    HttpModuleCollection mods = ctx.Modules;
    System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule ssm = (SessionStateModule)mods.Get("Session");
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = ssm.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    SessionStateStoreProviderBase store = null;
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo rqIdField = null, rqLockIdField = null, rqStateNotFoundField = null;
    foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        if (field.Name.Equals("_store")) store = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)field.GetValue(ssm);
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqId")) rqIdField = field;
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqLockId")) rqLockIdField = field;
        if (field.Name.Equals("_rqSessionStateNotFound")) rqStateNotFoundField = field;
    }
    object lockId = rqLockIdField.GetValue(ssm);
    if ((lockId != null) && (oldId != null)) store.ReleaseItemExclusive(Context, oldId, lockId);
    rqStateNotFoundField.SetValue(ssm, true);
    rqIdField.SetValue(ssm, newId);
```

Comment: could you share what is your iis environment? you hosted the same application in iis with two names or both are a different application. please attach folder structure and iis site snapshot.

Comment: IIS7.5, Both are same application with different version of code